# how to put the result in a text file?

Tags: php, fsockopen

the code:

```
   if ($conn = fsockopen ("whois.crsnic.net", 43)) {
        fputs($conn, $domain."\r\n");
        while(!feof($conn)) {
            $output .= fgets($conn,128);
        }
        fclose($conn);
```

now,i  want to put the output of `$conn`  and `$output` in two text file. how shoud i do? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really write the contents of $conn, as it's a resource handler, however you can write the contents of $output to a file:

```
file_put_contents('filename', $output);
```

Comment: where is the file in when i use file_put_contents

Comment: Thanks guys. I knew I should have checked the php manual... fixed

Comment: @zhuanzhou: the file is `'filename'` as per the documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).